# Elemental concepts about Qt signals, events, QEventLoop, and connections

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to learn about the QEventLoop but I'm getting really confuse, and I would appreciate if somebody point me in the right documentation or tutorial direction. However I have no idea of what I want. So I'm going to describe a simple example, and maybe someone can actually understand it and tell me what this is called.

Lets say we have a main() function, that creates a little dialog called "comDialog".

ComDialog have a label with a status text, a line edit field, and a push button. The status text says: "Please write 'yes' in the edit field".

Now, the main() function have created the comDialog, and is waiting for somebody to click the push button. In order to do that, we just need to wait until it happens, and as far as I understand, here is where the QEventLoop goes with a connection with the on_pushButton_clicked() signal that comDialog.h have implemented.

However, I want the loop to start over if a certain condition doesn't occur. Here is the behavior. When the push button is press, comDialog send a signal or event to the main() with the string content of the text field. comDialog does nothing else, is up to main() to decide what to do. Now, the main() checks the signal content, and, if the text field string == "yes" everything is fine, the comDialog disappear, and the program continues.

But if it is not, now is the main() the one that send a signal, with a new string of the same content as the previous one, to comDialog, and it keeps waiting until the push button is pressed again, and again, and again until the condition is meet. In the other side, when comDialog receive the signal, it update the label to: "You wrote "+signal+" instead of 'yes'!", and it just stays there until somebody write something and press the button.

So what should I search? How do you make the QEventLoop to go back in both the main and dialog?

Comment: If you do that you will become a bad developer. You can create a [timer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/timers.html) in the background, so after the UI is shown you can wait some amount of time, after that can do whatever you want. But don't exit/re-run the thread...IMO is not good intuitive. If the objective of the UI is just wait the user to push a button, I think a timer in the background, which autoclose the dialog after some idle period, is a good start.

Comment: you are messing so many things, `main()` cannot emit/receive signals. signals/slots only have meaning with `QObject`s.

Comment: `while(!somecondition){dialog.exec(); if(dialog.text() == "yes") somecondition = true;}`